# Update value based on checkbox selected

Tags: php, html

I am trying to update the value in a text box based on selections made on the form. When a user checks a box for an option, I am trying to get the total cost to increase by a defined amount. Everything else is working on the form and if I change the cost value manually it will post to database correctly. Is this possible with my approach or do I need to resort to a different technique?

```
<HEAD>
<script>
function tally()
{
    Cost = 60;

    if (Document.edituser.survivor10.checked ) { Cost = Cost + 10;    }
    if (document.edituser.high5.checked ) { Cost = Cost + 10;    }
    if (document.edituser.margin.checked == true ) { Cost = Cost + 10;  }
    if (document.edituser.survivor20.checked == true ) { Cost = Cost + 20;  }
    if (document.edituser.confidence.checked == true ) { Cost = Cost + 10;  }
    if (document.edituser.loser.checked == true ) { Cost = Cost + 10;  }
    if (document.edituser.vegas.checked == true ) { Cost = Cost + 10;  }                
    document.edituser.cost.value =  Cost;

}
```

```
<?php
require('includes/application_top.php');

include('includes/classes/class.formvalidation.php');

if (isset($_POST['submit'])) {
$my_form = new validator;

if($my_form->checkEmail($_POST['email'])) { // check for good mail

    if ($my_form->validate_fields('firstname,lastname,email,password')) { // 
comma delimited list of the required form fields
        if ($_POST['password'] == $_POST['password2']) {
            $salt = substr($crypto->encrypt((uniqid(mt_rand(), true))), 0, 10);
            $secure_password = $crypto->encrypt($salt . $crypto->encrypt($_POST['password']));
            $sql = "update nflp_users ";
            $sql .= "set password = '".$secure_password."', salt = '".$salt."', firstname = '".$_POST['firstname']."', lastname = '".$_POST['lastname']."',  textOption = '".$_POST['textOption']."', phone = '".$_POST['phone']."', carrier = '".$_POST['carrier']."', email = '".$_POST['email']."', survivor10 = '".$_POST['survivor10']."', survivor20 = '".$_POST['survivor20']."', loser = '".$_POST['loser']."', margin = '".$_POST['margin']."', high5 = '".$_POST['high5']."', vegas = '".$_POST['vegas']."', confidence = '".$_POST['confidence']."', cost = '".$_POST['cost']."'";               
            $sql .= "where userID = " . $user->userID . ";";
            //die($sql);
            $mysqli->query($sql) or die($mysqli->error);

            //set confirmation message
            $display = '<div class="responseOk">Account updated successfully.</div><br/>';
        } else {
            $display = '<div class="responseError">Passwords do not match, please try again.</div><br/>';
        }
    } else {
        $display = str_replace($_SESSION['email_field_name'], 'Email', $my_form->error);
        $display = '<div class="responseError">' . $display . '</div><br/>';
    }
} else {
    $display = '<div class="responseError">There seems to be a problem with your email address, please check.</div><br/>';
}
}

include('includes/header.php');

$sql = "select * from " . DB_PREFIX . "users where userID = " . $user->userID;
$query = $mysqli->query($sql);
if ($query->num_rows > 0) {
$row = $query->fetch_assoc();
$firstname = $row['firstname'];
$lastname = $row['lastname'];
$email = $row['email'];
$survivor10 = $row['survivor10'];
$survivor20 = $row['survivor20'];
$loser = $row['loser'];
$margin = $row['margin'];
$high5 = $row['high5'];
$confidence = $row['confidence'];
$vegas = $row['vegas'];
//  $textOption = $row['textOption'];
//  $phone = $row['phone'];
//  $carrier = $row['carrier'];
$cost = $row['cost'];

}

if (!empty($_POST['firstname'])) $firstname = $_POST['firstname'];
if (!empty($_POST['lastname'])) $lastname = $_POST['lastname'];
if (!empty($_POST['email'])) $email = $_POST['email'];
if (!empty($_POST['survivor10'])) $survivor10 = $_POST['survivor10'];
if (!empty($_POST['survivor20'])) $survivor20 = $_POST['survivor20'];
if (!empty($_POST['loser'])) $loser = $_POST['loser'];
if (!empty($_POST['margin'])) $margin = $_POST['margin'];
if (!empty($_POST['high5'])) $high5 = $_POST['high5'];
if (!empty($_POST['confidence'])) $confidence = $_POST['confidence'];
if (!empty($_POST['vegas'])) $vegas = $_POST['vegas'];
// if (!empty($_POST['textOption'])) $textOption = $_POST['textOption'];
// if (!empty($_POST['phone'])) $phone = $_POST['phone'];
// if (!empty($_POST['carrier'])) $carrier = $_POST['carrier'];
if (!empty($_POST['cost'])) $cost = $_POST['cost'];
?>
<h1>Edit User Account Details</h1>
<?php if(isset($display)) echo $display; ?>
<form action="user_edit.php" method="post" name="edituser">
    <fieldset>
    <legend style="font-weight:bold;">Enter User Details:</legend>
        <p>First Name:<br />
        <input type="text" name="firstname" value="<?php echo $firstname; ?>"></p>

        <p>Last Name:<br />
        <input type="text" name="lastname" value="<?php echo $lastname; ?>"></p>

        <p>Email:<br />
        <input type="text" name="email" value="<?php echo $email; ?>" size="30"></p>

        <p>New Password:<br />
        <input type="password" name="password" value=""></p>

        <p>Confirm Password:<br />
        <input type="password" name="password2" value=""></p><br>
        <tr><td></td></tr>
    <legend style="font-weight:bold;">Side Pools:</legend>
    <tr>
        <p><type=hidden value=" " name="survivor10" checked>        
        <INPUT onclick=tally() TYPE="checkbox" value="1" NAME="survivor10" <? if($survivor10== "1") {echo "checked";} ?>><b> Survivor $10</b></p>
        <p><type=hidden value=" " name="survivor20" checked>
        <INPUT onclick=tally() TYPE="checkbox" value="1" NAME="survivor20" <? if($survivor20== "1") {echo "checked";} ?>><b> Survivor2 $20</b></p>
        <p><type=hidden value=" " name="loser" checked>
        <INPUT onclick=tally() TYPE="checkbox" value="1" NAME="loser" <? if($loser== "1") {echo "checked";} ?> ><b> Loser $10</b></p>       
        <p><type=hidden value=" " name="high5" checked>
        <INPUT onclick=tally() TYPE="checkbox" value="1" NAME="high5" <? if($high5== "1") {echo "checked";}  ?>><b> High 5 $10</b></p>
        <p><type=hidden value=" " name="margin" checked>
        <INPUT onclick=tally() TYPE="checkbox" value="1" NAME="margin" <? if($margin== "1") {echo "checked";} ?> ><b> Margin $10</b></p>
        <p><type=hidden value=" " name="vegas" checked>
        <INPUT onclick=tally() TYPE="checkbox" value="1" NAME="vegas" <? if($vegas== "1") {echo "checked";} ?> ><b> Vegas $10</b></p>
        <p><type=hidden value=" " name="confidence" checked>
        <INPUT onclick=tally() TYPE="checkbox" value="1" NAME="confidence" <? if($confidence== "1") {echo "checked";} ?>><b> Confidence $10</b></p>
    </tr><br>
        <td><font color=red>Your Total Fee Is :</font><input type="int" size="3"  name="cost" value= "<? if($cost!= "") {echo "$cost"; } else {echo "60";}?>"</td><br><br>
<!--<tr>Text alert option: Message and data rates may apply. Expect approx. 3 msgs/week.</tr> -->
        <p><input type="submit" name="submit" value="Submit" class="btn btn-primary"></p>

    </fieldset>
</form>
```

Comment: Do not use short tags `<?` always use proper full opening `<?php`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

JavaScript is case sensitive, so `Document` and `document` are two different things. In your case, you want to use `document`. So you should change all if conditions inside tally, to use `document`.

Btw. never trust the user! You could do the calculation on the client side as an indicator for the user, but you should definitly do it again on the serverside or everyone could post costs as the like - even negative ones.

Comment: That was it - rookie mistake on my part. The first "Document" was capitalized... changing it makes it work! Thanks!